# prove that log((n^2)!)= o(log((n!)^2))

Tags: asymptotics, factorial

i have a question - how i can prove that:

> $\log((n^2)!) =\theta (log((n!)^2))$

i try something like that:

$\log((n^2)!) = 2*(log(n)!)=\theta(2*(log(n)!)=\theta(n\ log(n)) $

$\ \theta(log(n!)^2)=\theta(log(n!)*log(n!)) = \theta(n\ log(n)) $

then we can see that is equal  --> there are $\theta(n\ log(n))$

this is true?

Comment: log((2)!)=2∗(()!) is wrong.

Comment: You can't do that, because $(n!)^2 < (n^2)!$

Comment: Not just <, but an awful lot less.

Comment: Welcome to StackOoverflow! This question has been downvoted due to poor formatting. It is not clear if you mean "big theta of" or "little o of"

Answer (score 1):

$(n^2)!$ is the product of the numbers 1 to $n^2$.

$(n!)^2$ is the product of the numbers 1 to n, multiplied by the product of the numbers 1 to n again.

In the first product, we have $n^2 - n$ numbers ≥ n plus some others. In the second product we have 2n numbers ≤ n. So if we take the logarithm, the first is ≥ $(n^2 - n) log n$, the second is ≤ $2n log n$. So f(n) / g(n) ≥ (n-1)/2. Absolutely not Big-$\Theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: $(n^2)!$ is the product of $n^2$ numbers. We can split the product into n groups 1 .. n, n+1 .. 2n, 2n+1 .. 3n, $n^2-n+1$ .. $n^2$. The product of the numbers in each group is ≥ n!, actually significantly greater than n! in some cases. So $(n^2)! ≥ (n!)^n$.

If we let f(n) = $log ((n^2)!)$ and g(n) = $log((n!)^2)$, then f(n) ≥ n log(n!), while g(n) = 2 log(n!), so f(n) / g(n) ≥ n/2. So f(n) is not o (g(n)), or $\Theta(g(n))$, but g(n) = o (f(n)).